# How to check and change labels and textboxes in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to make a website using `asp.net`. First you must log in. This textbox is called `Username`, and there is a textbox called `Password`.

If `Username = Hello` and `Password = 123`, then I want the page to redirect. If it doesn't match then I want a pre-existing label called `ErrorMessage` to display a message saying: `Please check Username and password`.

Here is my current code in the button click event.
Nothing works so far.

```
If (Username.Text.Contains("Hello")) & (Password.Text.Contains("123")) Then
   Response.Redirect("MemberContactInfo.aspx")
Else
   ErrorMessage.Text = "Please check username and password"
End If
```

Comment: Watch out: a typed password of "012345" also Contains "123" - is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator in your `If` statement. When you want two conditions to be true, you should use the `And` operator, not the `&` operator (which performs string concatenation).

Modify your code as follows:

```
If (Username.Text.Contains("Hello")) And (Password.Text.Contains("123")) Then
    Response.Redirect("MemberContactInfo.aspx")
Else
    ErrorMessage.Text = "Please check username and password"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!